# Why did the Nazis have such a technological advantage in Wolfenstein: The New Order?

Tags: wolfenstein-the-new-order

In Wolfenstein: The New Order, the premise is that Nazi Germany won WWII, contrary to normal history. I understood that this was due to vastly superior tech, but why did their tech outpace the rest of the world so much?

I have played through the game already, and I can't really remember them explaining this directly. The big issue is that the game starts after the Nazis have basically already won the war: the first mission is a last-ditch effort to maybe win the war, but the missions after that are all set after the war has ended, in a resistance-style storyline. There is not much explanation that i remember as to why the Nazi tech is so much better.

Comment: To those that downvoted me: I'm perfectly willing to rework my question to improve it, but I have to know what's wrong with it first.

Comment: At one point in the game you end up in a big vault of advanced weaponry belonging to some secret technology. My vague recollection is that the Nazis captured one or more of these prior to the war and used its secrets to build out their army. I don't remember any specifics though.

Comment: Its worth noting that asking about downvotes, and indeed, posting about it on meta, is known to lead to more downvotes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Nazis didn't develop their advanced technology - they stole it from the fictional Da'at Yichud. The Da'at Yichud are a secretive sect of scholars who tirelessly work to create highly advanced technology, and have done so throughout human history. The caveat being they believe that the act of creation alone is enough - these inventions were never intended to be used. General Deathshead stumbled upon one of many technological caches, and pilfered what he found there for his own purposes. Some of the technology has been reverse-engineered by the nazis, which was enough to give them their huge technological advantage seen in game.